# Jquery append data attribute value dynamically using html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery sortable library where i will drop item from one list to another.In the process of dropping item i will change html content.I have data attribute also.

```
onAdd: function (evt) {            
  var df="hm "+evt.item.innerText;
  alert(df);
  var content='<div class="list-group-item " >'+evt.item.innerText+' its modified  <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill float-right" data-job='+df+'>14</span></div>';

  $(evt.item).replaceWith(content);

},
```

in alert i get correct appended value but in `data-job` it will set only hm and evt.item.innerText will not append

Can any one help me to append it properly.

Thank you

Comment: Try `data-job="'+df+'"` quotes for attribute. Otherwise your code seems correct

Comment: @murli2308.add it as answer i will accept it

Comment: You'd be better off just deleting the question as it was a typographical mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes in the expression

Use below code
    `data-job="'+df+'"`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have space between the text, the text after the space is treated as ***another attribute*** of the element. You should wrap the text with quotes `data-job="'+df+'"`.

Though I prefer using [**Template literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which is more cleaner and easier to use:

> *Template literals* are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the ES2015 specification.

**Demo:**

```js
function test(evt) {
  var df="hm "+evt.target.innerText;
  var content=`<div class="list-group-item">evt.target.innerText its modified  <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill float-right" data-job='${df}'>14</span></div>`;
  console.log(df);
  console.log(content);
  $('body').append(content);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="test(event)">test</div>
```